# Click specific element inside card

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an example card that has a button inside. When I click the card, a log will appear that the card is clicked, but when I click the button a log message appears that I clicked the card **and** the button.

It should only show the log message for the button when clicking on the button. Not the card.

How to handle this problem?

```js
$('.cards-trigger').on('click', function(){
    console.log('cards-trigger')
});

$('.button-trigger').on('click', function(){
    console.log('button-trigger')
});

$('.cards').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).siblings().trigger('click')
});

$('.add-button').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).siblings().trigger('click')
});
```

```css
.cards{
  padding:20px;
  background-color:grey;
}

.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, molestias.</p>
  <button class="add-button">Add</button>
  <button class="hidden button-trigger">BT</button>
</div>
<button class="hidden cards-trigger">CT</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

By clicking button you're also click card. First thrown event for button, then for card (and so on traversing up to the body and html). If you don't want event to propaggate add event.stopPropagation() like:

```
$('#buttonAdd').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('click the button')
})
```

notice, I've added event parameter (e) to your function.

Comment: I've edited the snippet above using stopPropagation(). But still trigger the card @Graf

Comment: I don't know, what you're trying to achieve. If you just want to message when card or button clicked, then milt_on has given much better answer with working code snippet. In your example you stop propagation first, but then manualy propagate event with trigger(click), and call $('.button-trigger').on('click',  without e.stopPropagation(), so event propagete from .button-trigger to card. in you example you should add return false (or event.stopPropagation) to $('.button-trigger').on('click', or use simplier solution    given by milt_on.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `return false` at the end of your child function (#buttonAdd) to prevent event propagation.

Alternatively you could add a `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event propagation.
See here: [jQuery stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```js
$('.cards').on('click', function(){
    console.log('click the card')
})

$('#buttonAdd').on('click', function(){
    console.log('click the button')
    return false
})
```

```css
.cards{
  padding:20px;
  background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate, eveniet.</p>
  <button id="buttonAdd">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited the snippet above using stopPropagation(). But still trigger the card  @milt_on

Answer (score -1):

While calling the button inside the card, add `stopPropagation()` to the button function which will stop it from calling the parent(that is the card component function as well)

```
 event.stopPropagation();
```

In your case,

```
$('#buttonAdd').on('click', function(event){
console.log('click the button')
return false
event.stopPropagation();
```